# Java/Json - Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token

Tags: java, json, mongodb, postman, mongodb-java

I have a basic project that when teachers login to system could add courses and when students login to system could select the course and add to their course list. I use MongoDB as database. My problem is, when I want to add new course to student's course list, I get some error. Here is my PUT annotation for updating course list:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/")
public User updateCourses(User user) {
    MongoCollection usersCollection = MongoConnector.getUserCollection();
    UserService userService = new UserService(usersCollection);
    User updatedUser = userService.updateCourses(user);
    return updatedUser;
}
```

And here is my User model:

```
public class User {

private String email;
private String pass;
private String type;
private List<String> courses;


public User(){

}

public User(String email, String pass, String type, List<String> courses) {
    this.email = email;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.type = type;
    this.courses = courses;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public List<String> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(List<String> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}}
```

My Json model:

```
{
"email": "deneme@student.com",
"pass": "4",
"type": "student",
"courses": [
    "Deneme1",
    "Deneme2",
    "Deneme3",
    "Deneme4"
]
```

}

And as final my userService funstion to add new course to course list of student:

```
public User updateCourses (User user){

    userCollection.updateOne(eq("email", user.getEmail()),Updates.addToSet("courses", user.getCourses()));
    return user;
}
```

I get this error from Postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMTRU.png)

As I have searched, I found that my code returns String instead of Json that could be the problem. But I also tried to convert user to Json with Gson but didn't work. How can I pass this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In your `User` class, `courses` is a `List` of `String`.

So when you attempt to send `"courses": "Deneme 5"` in the JSON payload  of your Postman request, you get an error.

Try sending `"courses": ["Deneme 5"]` instead.